# solving the equation where two variables are used

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Solve the equation $$\frac{x}{x-a} + x = \frac{b}{b-a}+ b$$ 
         The equation doesn't make sense. Should we take the LCM .only one equation and two variabkes are given

Comment: Please check if my edit is correct. BTW what are the variables?

Comment: I think that the only variable is $x$ and $b,a$ are just constant, If this is the case there is two solutions $b$ and $\cdots $

Comment: Which of those are variable?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start with $$\frac{x}{x-a} + x = \frac{b}{b-a}+ b$$ Now, multiply both sides by the product of denominators, that is to say by $(x-a)(b-a)$. Simplify both sides and groups terms by same powers of $x$; you should arrive to something such as $$(b-a)x^2 + \left(a^2-a-b^2\right)x-a b (a-b-1)=0$$ which is a quadratic in $x$.

But looking at the original expression, the equality holds if $x=b$; so $b$ is a root of the equation. Then, what is the other one ?

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{x}{x-a} + x = \dfrac{b}{b-a}+ b$$
$$x+x(x-a) = \dfrac{b(x-a)}{b-a}+ b(x-a)$$
$$x^2 + x(1-a-\dfrac{b}{b-a}-b)+\dfrac{ab}{b-a}+ab=0$$
$x=b$ is an obvious root, so factoring:
$$(x-b)x +bx + (x-b)(1-a-\dfrac{b}{b-a}-b)+(b-ba-\dfrac{b^2}{b-a}-b^2)+\dfrac{ab}{b-a}+ab=0$$
Cancelling a few terms:
$$(x-b)x +bx + (x-b)(1-a-\dfrac{b}{b-a}-b)+(b-\dfrac{b^2}{b-a}-b^2)+\dfrac{ab}{b-a}=0$$
$$(x-b)x +bx + (x-b)(1-a-\dfrac{b}{b-a}-b)+(\dfrac{b^2-ab-b^2}{b-a}-b^2)+\dfrac{ab}{b-a}=0$$
$$(x-b)x +bx + (x-b)(1-a-\dfrac{b}{b-a}-b)-b^2=0$$
$$(x-b)x  + (x-b)(1-a-\dfrac{b}{b-a}-b)+b(x-b)=0$$
$$(x-b)[x  + 1-a-\dfrac{b}{b-a}]=0$$
So the other root is $x=\dfrac{b}{b-a}+a-1=\dfrac{a(b-a+1)}{b-a}$